# Trouble with R function POSIXct recognising the time format of my file

Tags: r, xts, posixct

I'd like to know why this R statement is unable to interpret the time format provided in my dataset column `Occurred Date / Time`? I'm attempting to index the .dataframe and order by Occurred Date / Time column.

```
> head (test[,c(0:4)])
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  `Template ID` `Reported Date` `Reported Time` `Occurred Date / Time`
          <int>           <chr>          <time>                 <dttm>
1        124529       1/02/2016        00:32:00    2016-01-31 23:19:20
2        126305       6/02/2016        06:42:00    2016-02-06 05:46:48
3        126921       6/02/2016        12:28:00    2016-02-06 10:22:05
4        127035       9/02/2016        04:26:00    2016-02-09 03:59:58
5        127916      11/02/2016        17:25:00    2016-02-11 16:35:19
6        128340      10/02/2016        10:38:00    2016-02-10 09:33:01

xts(test[, -1], order.by = as.POSIXct(test[,c(4)],format="%d-%m-%Y  %H:%M:%S")) 

Error message;
 > xts(test[, -1], order.by = as.POSIXct(test[,c(4)],format="%d-%m-%Y  %H:%M:%S"))
Error in as.POSIXct.default(test[, c(4)], format = "%d-%m-%Y  %H:%M:%S") : 
  do not know how to convert 'test[, c(4)]' to class “POSIXct”
```

Comment: Look at the format you are passing: `format="%d-%m-%Y`. The dataframe has `%Y-%m-%d`. And when it's `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` there is no need for a format specification string. I will vote to close as *This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers*.

Comment: Sorry, Rui, I was tired when posting I had already attempted without the use of formatting. I think the problem stemmed from how I was referencing the column in the XTS function which distracted me. It all worked after renaming the column with no spaces or slash. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Check your colunm `Ocurred Date/Time` (example `2016-02-10 09:33:01`), format is "%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S" but you set `format="%d-%m-%Y  %H:%M:%S"`

If you have troubles with format, library `anytime` may help you:

```
library(anytime)
anytime("2016-02-10 09:33:01")
```

It tries to guess the format of you dates!

Comment: Thank You Jonny, As per my comment to Rui. Kind Regards